# Javascript not executing when placed in external script file

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, scripting, external-script

I'm building an ASP.NET MVC site where I need a tag editor, similar to the one used on Stack Overflow. I've already looked up how to accomplish the necessary autocompletion with jQuery UI, but I've run into a problem: **when I place the script in an external `.js` file, it doesn't execute**.

Here is my `test.html`:

```
<html> 
<head> 
    <meta charset="utf-8"> 
    <title>Test</title> 
    <script src="http://jqueryui.com/jquery-1.4.2.js"></script> 
    <script src="http://jqueryui.com/ui/jquery.ui.core.js"></script> 
    <script src="http://jqueryui.com/ui/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script> 
    <script src="http://jqueryui.com/ui/jquery.ui.position.js"></script> 
    <script src="http://jqueryui.com/ui/jquery.ui.autocomplete.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.tagautocomplete.js"></script>
    <script> 
    $(function() { bindAutoTagComplete('#birds'); })
    </script>
</head> 
<body> 
    <label for="birds">Birds: </label> 
    <input id="birds" size="50" /> 
</body> 
</html>
```

Here's `jquery.tagautocomplete.js`:

```
function bindAutoTagComplete(item, otherRootDomain)
{
        function split( val ) {
            return val.split( / \s*/ );
        }
        function extractLast( term ) {
            return split( term ).pop();
        }

        $(item).autocomplete({
            source: function( request, response ) {
                $.getJSON('http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/search.php', {
                    term: extractLast( request.term )
                }, response );
            },
            search: function() {
                // custom minLength
                var term = extractLast( this.value );
                if ( term.length < 2 ) {
                    return false;
                }
            },
            focus: function() {
                // prevent value inserted on focus
                return false;
            },
            select: function( event, ui ) {
                var terms = split( this.value );
                // remove the current input
                terms.pop();
                // add the selected item
                terms.push( ui.item.value );
                // add placeholder to get the comma-and-space at the end
                terms.push( "" );
                this.value = terms.join( " " );
                return false;
            }
        });
    }
```

**What do you think may be causing this problem?** I'm probably missing some closing parantheses/braces in the `.js` file...

*Thanks in advance!*

Comment: Are you sure the file's being included?  Try just placing `alert("test")` in the file and seeing if it fires.

Comment: @Nick OK, will test in a sec. Should I put it after `function bindAutoTagComplete(iteme,otherRootDomain) {` or before? **UPDATE:** I've tried both ways; only putting it before the function declaration worked. That means the file is being loaded, but for some reason, my function isn't executing. What gives? Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Maxim - at the very top of the file works...anywhere in the base is valid.

Comment: Other info: When putting that code into a `<script>` block on the HTML page, it executes and I see a request to `search.php` in FireBug. However, when it's setup like this, no request appears.

Comment: @Maxim - where is that `.js` file?  The way you have it, it has to be in the same directory as the webpage.

Comment: @Nick they're both on my desktop. :)

Am I calling the function incorrectly from within the HTML page?

Comment: @Maxim - That isn't the issue..at least yet, you should be seeing an alert if it's in the file or you should be seeing some error in your console, what is it?  Also try adding a MIME type: `<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.tagautocomplete.js"></script>`

Comment: When I set up the example html and js files you posted, the script executes just fine. But when inspected the response in fireBug, I got an empty response, probably due to the cross-domain issues.

Comment: @ArtBIT hmm... For me, FireBug shows no request/response at all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to attach that event after the page is ready. #birds doesn't exist when it runs currently.

Something like

```
<script>
$(document).ready( function(){  bindAutoTagComplete('#birds'); } );

</script>
```

Comment: This is incorrect, `$(function() {` is a shortcut for `$(document).ready(function(){`, so he's already dunning this on `document.ready`.

Comment: That seems to fix the problem. Thanks so much!

Comment: @Maxim - You have another underlying issue, or made another change, there is *no* difference in the code posted in the answer here.

Comment: @Nick - where have you seen that shortcut documented?

Comment: @Nik - It's in the API: `$(callback)`: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery3 You'll find it in thousands of SO questions :)

Comment: I agree with @Nick-Craver, this change should have no impact on your code whatsoever.

Comment: Hmm, that's true, but I didn't make any other changes! Very strange... oh well, at least it works now!