# I have built autocomplete input box (but there is a problem with foucsout)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, autocomplete

I have built autocomplete input box (but there is a problem with foucsout)

**Watch this :**
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IxlXWfJsSeM

Demo:
http://www.faressoft.org/autocomplete/

My HTML Code :

```
<div class="autoCompleteDiv">
    <input type="text" value="" size="60" name="countryName" id="countryName" class="autocomplete">
    <ul class="autoCompleteList"></ul>
</div>
```

My jQuery Code :

```
$(".autocomplete").focusout(function() {
$(".autoCompleteList").css("display","none");
});
```

**result should be like the tags input box of stackoverflow**

---

*Adding actual code from link. --patrick dw*

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
    $(".autocomplete").attr("value","");
    $(".autocomplete").keyup(function() {
        $(".autoCompleteList").css("display","none");
        if ($(this).attr("value")!="") {
            $(".autoCompleteList").width($(this).width()+3);
            $(".autoCompleteList").css("display","block");
            var Value = $(this).attr("value");
            $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "Tags.php",
            data: "country=" + Value,
            dataType: "html",
            success: function(data) {
                if (data!="") {
                    $(".autoCompleteList").html(data);
                    var re = new RegExp("(" + Value + ")", "gi");
                    $('.autoCompleteList').html($('.autoCompleteList').html().replace(re, '<span>$1</span>'));
                    $(".autoCompleteList li").click(function() {
                        $(".autocomplete").attr("value", $(this).text());
                    });
                } else {
                    $(".autoCompleteList").css("display","none");
                }
            }
            }); 
        }
    });
    $(".autocomplete").focusout(function() {
        //$(".autoCompleteList").css("display","none"); Watch the video. I can't choose the country.
    });         
});
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Problem with focusout (jQuery)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3954857/problem-with-focusout-jquery)

Comment: @patrick dw : I deleted "Problem with focusout (jQuery)"

Comment: faressoft - As **@Sep O Sep** answered, the code in your question is commented out. It works when I run your page with the uncommented code. I edited the question to include the code from the link.

Comment: Good job so far! However, **I would advise you against reinventing the wheel on this one**. I actually just built a tag input control myself that is really similar in functionality to the Stack Overflow one (as I'm building a site that requires it). Instead of writing it from scratch (well, with plain jQuery), I followed the code path from Stack Overflow to this plugin (http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-autocomplete/), but decided to use jQuery UI's autocomplete function instead, as it's newer. My code is mostly at: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3897150/. Hope that helps!

Comment: think my code should work now for you

Answer (score 4):

Okay i added the `$(".autoCompleteList").hide();` line to the click event handler and rewrote the code a little bit:

```
$(function(){ // shorthand for doc.ready     
    (function(){     
        var $input = $(".autocomplete"), // caching
            $list = $(".autoCompleteList");
       $input.attr("value","").keyup(function() {
            $list.hide();
            if ($(this).attr("value")!=="") {
            $list.width($(this).width()+3).show();      
            var val = $(this).attr("value"); // dont use value as varaiable name
            $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "Tags.php",
            data: "country=" + val,
            dataType: "html",
            success: function(data) {
            if (data!=="") {
                //replacing data 
                var re = new RegExp("(" + val + ")", "gi");
                data = data.replace(re, '<span>$1</span>');
                $list.html(data);

                // binding click 
                    $(".autoCompleteList li").bind('click', function() {
                    $(".autocomplete").attr("value", $(this).text());
                    $(".autoCompleteList").hide();
                    });

            } else {
                $list.hide();
            }
            }
            }); 
        }
    });
    })(); // self executing
});
```

Comment: Watch the video. because I can't choose the country.

Comment: very good. but when i click on the page the list doesn't hide.

Comment: you could either bind a click event to the body or an mouseout event on the autocompleteDiv.